# Get application context returns null

Tags: android, applicationcontext

The following schema has been touted as the way to get application context from anywhere within my android app. But sometimes doing `MyApp.getContext()` returns null. I tried changing the schema by removing `static` from `getContext()` so that I would do `MyApp.getInstance().getContext()`. It still returns null. How do I fix this? **How do I get my application's context from anywhere within my app?**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'sometimes'? When exactly

Comment: `sometimes` Actually I believe it used to work, but in reality I couldn't tell you because right now it always crashes. so `sometimes` is just me being cautious.

Comment: What is the stacktrace when it crashes? Crashing is a very different behavior than returning null from a method.

Comment: I have meet same issue, has you resolved this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Create in `onCreate()` an instance of `getApplicationContext()` (`mContext`) then call `MyApp.getContext()`  from everywhere in your app and you will get your application context statically.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static Context mContext;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();    
    }
}
```

Remember to declare into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:name="com.mypackage.mypackage.MyApp">
...
...
...
</application>
```

Comment: The link solved my problem. I was missing `<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">`. Thanks.

Comment: `return instance.getApplicationContext()` works fine, no need to use `return mContext`.
Particularly when calling `instance.getApplicationContext()` from classes outside application in some cases like database, it is preferred to pass instance as context, and then call Application context.

Comment: i have this warning "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak ", how can i resolve this?

Comment: @juzamn in services sometime Myapp.getContext through null pointer exception

Comment: @do01 it's a application object. I don't think any leak willl affect application memory management.

Answer (score 12):

Create a static instance of the `Context` in your `OnCreate` and keep it till you want to get it from 
a getter method `getContext()`

**From the `Application` class:**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private static Context sContext;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    sContext = getApplicationContext();
    super.onCreate();
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return sContext;
}
}
```

**Declare it in your `Manifest`:**

```
<application android:name="com.package.name.MyApp">
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. +1. I was missing `<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following way to get the Application context.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp mAppInstance=null;
    public static Context appContext;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return mAppInstance;
    }

    public static MyApp get() {
        return get(appContext);
    }

    public static MyApp get(Context context) {
        return (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mAppInstance=this;
        appContext=getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

add the the application name inside the **Manifest** file

```
<application android:name="packagename.MyApp"/>
```

to get the context use
`MyApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1):

`instance` is never initialized and so has a default value of `null`. This means that `instance.getContext()` will throw a `NullPointerException`. To fix this, you need to initialize the `instance` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have not initialized instance and by default it's value would now be set to null. You need to assign it a value before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another root cause, is due to the buggy backup process. Please refer to

[Why backup related process might cause Application's onCreate is not executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211036/why-backup-related-process-might-cause-applications-oncreate-is-not-executed/57246212)

Answer (score 0):

For get an application context the module should use the application plugin.

### build.gradle (:module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

The library plugin has not an app context.