# How to pass room instance to JobService?

Tags: android, android-room, android-jobscheduler

To save something param to local in JobScheduler, I have implemented below JobService,

```kotlin
class MyJobService : JobService() {

  private var context = applicationContext

  private var db = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context, // ERROR
    AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
  ).build()

  override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    ... 
  }

  override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    // use db
    ...
  }
```

but `applicationContext` is not working with below error message,

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

so I'm trying another way that passing room instance to MyJobService in JobInfo,

```
val job = JobInfo.Builder(
   MY_BACKGROUND_JOB,
   ComponentName(context, MyJobService::class.java) // seems to can not passing any arguments for constructor
)
.build()
```

but in `Class<?>`, It seems to can't passing arguments.

How to use room instance in `onStartJob` ?

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994612/get-application-context-returns-null

Comment: That's not an elegant solution! You should not pass the context everywhere are create Room instances everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a (f.e.)`Repository` class that handles all interactions with Room. Create a singleton in your Application.

Then you only need to get it via `((MainApp) getApplication()).getRepository()`

Find a really good example on the [official Android examples Github](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence)!